# Missing Administrative Tools in Windows 8 64-bit

Tags: windows-8, shortcuts

I'm hoping someone can rescue me from reinstalling after putting so much work into my Windows 8 install (final version). I accidentally deleted the contents of this folder:

> `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Administrative Tools`

That folder just contained all the administrative tools shortcuts.

So now, I have no administrative tools. I emptied my recycle bin and system restore is also disabled. I'm hoping these shortcuts may be cached somewhere in a CAB file, or maybe someone can attach a copy of the shortcuts that were in this folder. Otherwise, it looks like I'd have to reinstall to get them back.

Comment: Nevermind, I will reinstall. I think I broke more than my start menu. :(

Comment: Those are shortcuts, you should still be able to run them from Control Panel.

Comment: If you have decided to reinstall, and this question is no longer relevant, please delete it.

Answer (score 1):

You can download a zip containing the missing shortcuts here:
http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/47860-administrative-tools-restore-missing-default-shortcuts.html

This worked for me ... however, what I don't know is, how these shortcuts actually get lost. It seems to happen fairly often as the existence of the page above shows.

I had this happen to my windows 8.1 install multiple times and I surely didn't delete these shortcuts deliberately. I do have the feeling, that it might have some thing to do with the windows update process running out of space and failing, as that had happened shortly before mine disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm hoping these shortcuts may be cached somewhere in a CAB file...

Try System File Checker. If they are system files, then SFC should repair them:

```
sfc.exe /scannow
```

I believe I used SFC to fix a missing/broken link to my Desktop from the Desktop Tile on that {disingenuous|stupid|hated} Metro launcher.

Microsoft also has a KB on the utility at [Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833).